# add multiple factory in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I add multiple factors in angularJS

it show me wrong

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('projectsEvaluationApp')
    .factory('EvaluationsService', EvaluationsService);
EvaluationsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function EvaluationsService ($resource) {
    var service = $resource('api/evaluations/:id', {}, {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        },
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    });

    return service;
}
  .factory('VisitService', VisitService);
})();
```

Comment: `angular
    .module('projectsEvaluationApp')
    .factory('EvaluationsService', EvaluationsService)
    .factory('VisitService', VisitService);` or `var app = angular
    .module('projectsEvaluationApp'); app.factory("factory1",...); app.factory("factory2",....)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a syntax error. The `VisitService` must be declared as follow.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    angular
        .module('projectsEvaluationApp')
        .factory('EvaluationsService', EvaluationsService) // factory one
        .factory('VisitService', VisitService); // factory two

    EvaluationsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function EvaluationsService ($resource) {
        var service = $resource('api/evaluations/:id', {}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
            }
        });

        return service;
    }

    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign app to a variable and use it to create multiple `Factories/Directives` Like following:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    app = angular.module('projectsEvaluationApp');
    app.factory('EvaluationsService', EvaluationsService);
    EvaluationsService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function EvaluationsService($resource) {
        var service = $resource('api/evaluations/:id', {}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
            }
        });

        return service;
    }
    app.factory('VisitService', VisitService);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple factories to `angular.module`.

An angular module is created once by specifying dependencies.

```
var module = angular.module('moduleName', [])`
```

Further to add factories or controllers to same module, one can get module as

```
var module = angular.module('moduleName')
```

Following snippet will work for you.

```
    angular.module('projectsEvaluationApp')
        .factory('EvaluationsService', function($resource) {
            var service = $resource('api/evaluations/:id', {}, {
                            'get': {
                                method: 'GET',
                                isArray: true
                            },
                            'query': {
                                method: 'GET',
                                isArray: true,
                            }
                        });

            return service;
        });

    angular.module('projectsEvaluationApp')
      .factory('VisitService', function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution already given in the other answers.

Tip: 
Another way to inject a service into another one (rather than using $inject):

```
app.factory('EvaluationsService', ['$resource', EvaluationsService]);

function EvaluationsService($resource) {...}
```